# Cordova - http request doesnt process local php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

This is my first cordova project. My http request doesn't process the local php file using POST. The code works and processes it properly when the php file is hosted on the server. But doesn't when the php file is local. Editing files directly on the server is such a hassle and takes alot of time rather than just having it locally. And I wanted to know the solution to this because it will really make the development much easier.

**Here is the Javascript Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input").on("focus", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
});

$("#loginBtn").click(function () {
    swal({
        title: "Logging in ...",
        imageUrl: "../images/ring-alt.gif",
        showConfirmButton: false,
    });
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    if (username != "") {
        if (password != "") {
            $.post("../php/login.php",
            {
                username: username,
                password: password
            },
            function (data, status) {
                alert(data);    
            });
        } else {
            sweetAlert("Oops...", "Please enter your password!", "error");
        }
    } else {
        sweetAlert("Oops...", "Please enter your username!", "error");
    }
});
});
```

alert(data) displays the whole php file instead of processing it. Whereas when it is accessed remotely is works fine.

**Here is the working js code (remote/hosted php files)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input").on("focus", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
});

$("#loginBtn").click(function () {
    swal({
        title: "Logging in ...",
        imageUrl: "../images/ring-alt.gif",
        showConfirmButton: false,
    });
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    if (username != "") {
        if (password != "") {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    if (this.responseText == "successsuccess") {
                        window.location.href = '../html/dashboard.html';
                    } else {
                        sweetAlert("Oops...", "Invalid username or password!", "error");
                        document.getElementById("password").value = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.sampleee.esy.es/login.php", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send("username=" + username + "&" + "password=" + password);
        } else {
            sweetAlert("Oops...", "Please enter your password!", "error");
        }
    } else {
        sweetAlert("Oops...", "Please enter your username!", "error");
    }
});
});
```

**Now here is the php file**

```
<?php
include("connectdb.php");
$username = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
    $password = md5($password);

$getLogin = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $getLogin);
if(!$result){
   echo "Query Error: ". mysqli_error($conn);
   die();
}
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count == 1){
   echo "success";
}else{
       echo "failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: PHP code doesn't work in any environment; it needs to be actually processed by PHP-capable server. For local development, install a PHP dev env like xampp and send your AJAX requests to `localhost`.

Comment: Follow @ChrisG advice : build yourself a proper development/production pipeline. Build & test locally (ie your dev box hosts a local version of your server), then push to production when ready for prime-time. You will be able to design a well-constructed system that stands the test of `usage`.  Even if you discover along the way a method to have a server process 'local' php files, dont do that. Your server will be hacked deep in no time flat.

Comment: Appreciate the comments sir. Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to find a better way to edit php files to my server. Because everytime I make change I am editing it directly on the file manager of my server.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run PHP code on your cordova project. The PHP needs to be executed on a PHP-capable environement, like your server. Your php code also uses a database, and this database needs to be configured on a server, which can be done locally but then it would obviously not be shared between devices.

It seems you do not know exactlly what PHP is. You should start learning about it and understand how it works.

Comment: I think I am knowledgable enough to know that php runs on a server and uses a database. Just wanted to clarify things. I am a little bit confused too because I read articles that you use ajax to communicate with php in cordova. Cut me some slack :)

Comment: I had my database configured on a server. Just wanted to know if it is possible to process php locally but the database on a server.

Comment: Short answer: no.